# Creating site collection with SSL

Tags: 2010

I'm having an issue with what will be a production SharePoint server. It's a Win2008 R2 running SharePoint 2010. For database server we use a SQL 2008 R2 on a separate server. We have the luxury of having a test and dev environments with the same configuration and the problem is this:

On my dev environment I am able to creates web application on port 443 (SSL) but on the production server the page cannot be displayed. The wizard completes the process, database gets created and so it the virtual application in IIS.

Using the same service accounts on both environments just to get it started but no luck. I know what I've written is probably pretty vague but that is all I have. Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Thanks,
Risho

Comment: Alternate Access Mapping configured in SharePoint with matching bindings in IIS (including SSL)? Check the ULS logs for any errors? Check Server's Event Viewer for any .Net errors?

Comment: When web app and site collection were create I did check the "SSL" radio button and the IIS has created the virtual directory on port 443. There are several error pertaining to SharePoint Foundation in the event logs. No luck accessing ULS logs. Downloaded a viewer grom codex site but when I run that it only shows stuff as of the installation. As you can tell quite a novice with SP2010. Thanks for your input.

Comment: IIS will be configured but you need to add an SSL cert in IIS.

Comment: In SSL Settings I've checked Reguire SLL and set the cert to Accept. What's strange is that on my dev and test servers I can creates a site with SSL and the process automatically sets everyting up.

Comment: did that fix it?

Comment: No it did not fix it. So apperantly the admins have recently renamed the actual server to coincide with system wide naming convention and they advised me to reinstall SharePoint. Which I did but now I can't even get the central admin page to come up. I get the 500 error and everytime I refresh the page the app pool gets turned off.

Comment: Take a look in the registry, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS, and check out the Central Admin URL. Make sure you're accessing the right one. Ccheck IIS as well, make sure sites are running.